# VScode: How to exclude some folders from npm script search

Tags: visual-studio-code, npm-scripts

For trying to solve a problem in an Electron project in VsCode, I've made a backup of my node_modules folder and named it nodemodules_Back and paste a node_modules folder from a very close project. But now, in the sidebar, the npm scripts section is showing  all the npm scripts contained in the node_modulesBack folder. I understand that there should be probably in some place an indication to forbid the npm scripts search in the node_modules folder and wonder How I could add an excluded folder  to delete the included scripts to show up in the sidebar?.

Comment: I've found what could be a solution by adding the folder name in the "npm.exclude" property of the setting.json file of VsCode. The only annoying detail is that is not project related....

Answer (score 1):

I used VScode for long time and badly **didn't use and even know** [this basic features](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings). So I created `settings.jon` in the `.vscode` folder and put there my excluding setting

```
"npm.exclude": [     
        "**/node_modulesBak/**"
      ],
```

So Task of the day: read the documentation....